# How can I add an image line under h2 element?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to place an image under each h2 (some kind of design line). When I use h2:after, the image will show, but after resize the window the image doesn't resize width so it breaks website. Can you help me? Image has 730px x 20px resolution.

What I want:
http://i60.tinypic.com/14buc0z.png

Problem with resize, content image has still width 100% = 730px:
http://i62.tinypic.com/2eywa44.png

My code:

```
h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

h2:after {
  content: url(images/separator.png) center;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: use mediaquery and 2 different sizes of image?

Answer (score 1):

Use `background` instead of pseudo element is a better choice to me.

```
h2 {
  background: url("images/separator.png") center bottom no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Like above, but you'll need adjust the values until it looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use background of the H2 itself:

```
h2 {
 background: url(images/separator.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Or to use `<hr />` element instead and set its background with image you want.